# Parse JSON using Newtonsoft.Json C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following json string:

```
{
  "data":
  {
    "id": "1",
    "city": "London"
  },
  "cityDetails":
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "location": "UK",   
    "th": 0,
    "title": "Default Group",
    }
  },
  "limit": 0.60451203584671021,
  "_id": "1234"
}
```

How can I extract the the 'city' name from the 'data' section of the JSON string using Newtonsoft.Json in C#.

Comment: Your json data isn't valid

Comment: What did you try to do, and what happened when you tried? Did you, for example, read the 'getting started' chapter on the newtonsoft web site, https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm?

Comment: I have tries lots and lots of combinations https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm but failed miserably.

Comment: @HarryBoy Are you sure you json data is correct?

Comment: Its the inner JSON from a larger JSON data object, its like an inner array which I am trying to get the first item of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
        // load your json here
        var obj = JObject.Parse(@"{
          ""data"":
          {
            ""id"": ""1"",
            ""city"": ""London""
          },
          ""_id"": ""1234""
        }"); 

        // get the city
        var city = (string)obj.SelectToken("data.city");
```

You need to update the selected-token path if the JSON you provided is part of/inside another.